# Select indexes of intervals in Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Assuming you have some 1d- numpy array like
`arr = np.array([0,0,0.2,0.6,1,1,0.7,0.3,0,0])`

Here if would be `fn(arr, arr > 0.5) => [(3,6)]` <- indexes of inverval where the values are biggen then given value.
Also there can be multiple intervals per each row, so the output `[(3,6),[300,302]...]`  is also possible.

Is it possible to do one-line, or any short written and optimal Numpy operation
to get indexes of interval with specific condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
arr = np.array([0, 0, 0.2, 0.6, 1, 1, 0.7, 0.3, 0, 0])

ranges = np.where(np.diff(arr > 0.5, prepend=0, append=0))[0].reshape(-1, 2)
ranges[:, 1] -= 1

print(ranges)
```

Prints:

```py
[[3 6]]
```

---

For:

```py
arr = np.array([0.6, 0.7, 0, 0, 0.8, 0.9])
```

Prints:

```py
[[0 1]
 [4 5]]
```

Comment: so it is  np.where, awsome thanks! I do not need to substract 1 or reshape

Comment: btw can you replace np.diff on something else?